# Perfect Bayesian Nash Equilibrium - Pooling / Sep

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Given the following question -

[image]

I'm required to find all the Perfect Bayesian Equilibrium and specifically state whether they are pooling / separating.

Struggling to understand what would be the types (beliefs) in that game, is it <D, D'> are the pooling, and <C' D> , <C' D'> are the separating?